# Python numpy : Matrix Inverses give unprecise results when multiplied

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse

Alright, so I have 3 numpy matrices :

```
m1 = [[  3   2   2 ...   2   2   3]
      [  3   2   2 ...   3   3   2]
      [500 501 502 ... 625 626 627]
      ...
      [623 624 625 ... 748 749 750]
      [624 625 626 ... 749 750 751]
      [625 626 627 ... 750 751 752]]

m2 = [[  3   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  3   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  2   3 500 ... 623 624 625]
      ...
      [  2   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  2   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  3   2 500 ... 623 624 625]]

m3 = [[     813      827   160500 ...   199983   200304   200625]
      [     830      843   164000 ...   204344   204672   205000]
      [  181317   185400 36064000 ... 44935744 45007872 45080000]
      ...
      [  221046   225867 43936000 ... 54744256 54832128 54920000]
      [  221369   226196 44000000 ... 54824000 54912000 55000000]
      [  221692   226525 44064000 ... 54903744 54991872 55080000]]
```

m1, m2 and m3 are very large square matrices (those examples are 128x128, but they can go up to 2048x2048). Also m1*m2=m3.

My goal is to obtain m2 by using only m1 and m3. Someone told me this was possible, as m1*m2=m3 implies that (m1**-1) * m3 = m2 (I believe it was that, please correct me if I'm wrong) ; so I calculated the inverse of m1 :

```
m1**-1 = [[ 7.70884284e-01 -8.13188394e-01 -1.65131146e+13 ... -2.49697170e+12
           -7.70160676e+12 -4.13395320e+13]
          [-3.38144598e-01  2.54532610e-01  1.01286404e+13 ... -3.64296085e+11
            2.60327813e+12  2.41783491e+13]
          [ 1.77721050e-01 -3.54566231e-01 -5.00564604e+12 ...  5.82415184e+10
           -5.98354744e+11 -1.29817153e+13]
          ...
          [-6.56772812e-02  1.54498025e-01  3.21826474e+12 ...  2.61432526e+11
            1.14203762e+12  3.61036457e+12]
          [ 5.82732587e-03 -3.44252762e-02 -4.79430664e+11 ...  5.10855381e+11
           -1.07679881e+11 -1.71485373e+12]
          [ 6.55360708e-02 -8.24446025e-02 -1.19618881e+12 ...  4.45713678e+11
           -3.48073716e+11 -4.89344092e+12]]
```

The result looked rather messy so I ran a test and multiplied m1**-1 and m1 to see if it worked :

```
(m1**-1)*m1 = [[-125.296875  , -117.34375   , -117.390625  , ..., -139.15625   ,
                -155.203125  , -147.25      ],
               [ 483.1640625 ,  483.953125  ,  482.7421875 , ...,  603.796875  ,
                 590.5859375 ,  593.375     ],
               [-523.22851562, -522.36328125, -523.49804688, ..., -633.07421875,
                -635.20898438, -637.34375   ],
               ...,
               [  10.58691406,   11.68945312,   10.29199219, ...,   14.40429688,
                  13.00683594,   11.609375  ],
               [  -5.32177734,   -5.47949219,   -4.63720703, ...,   -5.28613281,
                  -5.31884766,   -5.6015625 ],
               [  -4.93554688,   -3.58984375,   -3.24414062, ...,   -8.72265625,
                  -5.37695312,   -8.03125   ]]
```

The result is different from the one expected (identity matrix). My guess is that m1 is too big, causing numerical imprecision. But if that previous calculation to get an identity matrix doesn't work properly, then (m1**-1)*m3 surely won't (and it doesn't).
But I really can't decrease the matrix sizes for m1, m2 and m3 and in fact I'd like it to work with even bigger sizes (as said before, max size would be 2048x2048).

Would there be any way to be more precise with such calculations ? Is there an alternative that could work for bigger matrices ?

Comment: In python `*` is elementwise multiplication. You need to use `@` for matrix multiplication and also if you want to invert use `linalg.solve` or at worst `linalg.inv`

Comment: @percusse `*` and `@` appear to give the same result. Also `linalg.solve` and `linalg.inv` don't work, as the determinant of `m1` is so close to 0, it's actually impossible to obtain `m2` afterwards. I'm currently trying to figure out a way to algorithmically generate `m1` in a certain way to have a non-zero determinant AND keep some calculations intact.

Comment: That's not possible. Try `np.ones((3,3)) @ np.ones((3,3))` and then try with `*`

Comment: @percusse Weird, this actually gives two different results, meanwhile on my program I tried `m1*m2 == m1@m2` and it returned an array of `True`.
What exactly would be the difference between elementwise multiplication for two numpy matrices and the matrix multiplication of two matrices ?

Comment: it means they are both diagonal matrices. or all zeros

Comment: @percusse And they aren't, which is even weirder.

Comment: Again that's not possible. That only means you have a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @percusse Tried this :
`m3 = m1*m2      
m4 = m1@m2      
print(m3.tolist() == m4.tolist())`
It printed `True`, so I guess that in this precise case `*` and `@` are the same. Maybe we aren't using the same version of Python and/or Numpy ? I use Python 3.6.4 with Numpy 1.14.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, inverting a large matrix can be inefficient and numerically unstable. Luckily, there are methods in linear algebra that solve this problem without requiring an inverse.

In this case, `m2 = np.linalg.solve(m1, m3)` works.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input !
Although I obtain a weird result that doesn't match the contains of m2 :
http://dl.free.fr/nXpK6PfSU
Are m1 and m3 still too big ?

Comment: Can you run `np.linalg.det(m1.T)`? If the result is `0`, then the rank condition fails and you will not be able to recover `m2`.

Comment: Result is `-0.0`. Is it a very small float rounded to 0, making it possible, or is it strictly 0 and therefore prevents any recovering of m2 ?

Comment: Practically speaking recovering `m2` will not be possible.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions regarding a non-random creation of m1 in a way that m2 could be recovered if only the first 2 rows of m1 are absolutely unchangeable and necessary ?

Comment: You need columns of `m2` to be linearly independent. Beyond that, making sure that the determinant is not too big and not soo small would probably help the numerical computation in some cases. I do not know an explicit procedure off the top of my head.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that.
Another question though : How come the linear independence of `m2`'s columns can impact the determinant of `m1` ?

Comment: Typo, I meant for columns of `m1` to be linearly independent)

Comment: Alrighty, I'll see what I can do about this, and I'll get back to you if I still have any problems. Much thanks ! ^^

Comment: After a few days of research, I decided to not modify `m1` and instead use `np.linalg.pinv()` to calculate the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of `m1`, which doesn't require a non-singular matrix and mathematically allows me to find `m2`.
I'm validating your answer as it can prove useful in some other cases ; and it also helped me with understanding why it didn't work quite well. Thanks for helping !